# Angular pass and validate input as a Map

Tags: angular, typescript, dictionary

I have an input text where the user has to enter a string in Json format, so for example:

```
    "test":"value",
    "test2":"value2"
```

When submitting the input, I want to use it as a [Map](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/es6-typescript/mapset/) and pass it to my endpoint. What is the correct way to write values in the input so that I can create a Map? If I pass this input, the Map is not created correctly.
What I did was:

```
variables:Map = myInput;
```

or

```
 let variables:Map<String,any> = new Map(myInput);
```

and then tried to iterate through keyset, but it didn't work. How can I create a Map from a string input and check if is a correct Map? What is the correct syntax for the input string to be considered as Map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse()` to parse the input text and when it corresponds to an `Object` you can easily transform it to a `Map` by using `Object#entries()`:

```
const map = new Map(Object.entries(JSON.parse(inputValue)));
```

**Note** that `Object#entries()` is a es2017 feature. Make sure to include `es2017` in the `lib` section of `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": [
      ...,
      "es2017"
    ]
}
```

This is a minimal example of a reactive forms validator to check if the JSON code is valid and corresponds to an object:

```
const jsonValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl) => {
  try {
    const obj = JSON.parse(control.value);
    if (typeof obj !== 'object' || Array.isArray(obj)) {
      throw new TypeError('Top level node should be an object');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      parseError: error,
    };
  }
  return null;
};
```

Regarding the explicit typing of the `Map`: if you want to accept only some types of values in the code, you can add some checks in validation:

```
if (Object.values(obj).some(v => /* Check value type */)) {
  throw new TypeError('Values should be ...');
}
```

Checking the keys wouldn't make mush sense since in JSON they can only be strings.

Here is a full example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dnmfrg

Comment: Hi, it tells me that #entries does not exist for Object type

Comment: That's probably because it is an es2017 feature, check the latest edit

Comment: Hi, I've set "target": "ESNext", at runtime it works but compile throws error. Anyway thank you, the method works, I'll open a new question with the proper details for this problem.